# Deleting product gives 500 fatal error

Tags: magento-1.9, product, error

I'm running `Magento 1.9.3.3` and whenever I try to delete a product I get an `HTTP ERROR 500` page. Everything else seems to work normally.

**The error log says:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function joinRel() on boolean in
>   /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Tag.php on
>   line 127

This is the relevant section from that tag.php file:

```
    protected function _getProductEventTagsCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    return $this->getResourceCollection()
                    ->joinRel()
                    ->addProductFilter($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId())
                    ->addTagGroup()
                    ->load();
}
```

I can't find any reference to this online at all and I'm completely stumped. Has anyone got any ideas, or suggest a fix?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this error. Apparently `$this->getResourceCollection()` returns false. Just to be sure, did you try to clean the cache and reindex?

Comment: Yes, have cleared cache numerous times and re-indexed. No difference.

Comment: OK, very strange indeed. Did you recently activate or install any new modules that might have changed the behavior?

Comment: I had recently installed a social media button extension and changed the DNS to run through Cloudflare. I have now uninstalled that extension and changed the DNS back the way it was and no difference. Is it possible that an extension could make a permanent change? I may have to try loading backups onto a test site to see when this probem started.

Comment: I have loaded a backup onto a test site from July 2 (pre the social media button extension) and  it does delete products correctly. So it seems that the extension has created a persistant issue somehow. Thanks for your time. I will have to roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `$this->getResourceCollection()` returns `false`.

If you look at the code in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php, you can see that it tries to load a resource collection for a specified `_resourceCollectionName`:

```
public function getResourceCollection()
    {
        if (empty($this->_resourceCollectionName)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Model collection resource name is not defined.'));
        }
        return Mage::getResourceModel($this->_resourceCollectionName, $this->_getResource());
    }
```

Did you see anything in the error logs? Is the Exception thrown for example (`/var/log/exception.log` by default)? Look like Magento tries to load a resource Collection model that is somehow not defined.

Comment: The only thing in the exception.log file is a lot of repeated errors for invalid block type. - 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php:595. Pretty sure that this is a separate problem that I'm also going to have to sort out.

Comment: Problem solved - it was an extension that was causing the issue.